# Ftplib getting command return value

Tags: python, tkinter, ftplib

I'm making an FTP client with Tkinter and when I try to list files/directories, it prints it to the console, and it only puts `226 Transfer complete.` inside of my textbox. (Instead of putting the files in my textbox)

I've tried to do this:

```
files = self.ftp.retrlines('LIST')
self.targetFiles.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
self.targetFiles.delete('1.0', tk.END)
self.targetFiles.insert(tk.END, files)
self.targetFiles.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
```

But It just prints to the console.

Expected: Returns to the variable, using the variable to put in a textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!**
What you need to do is replace the command `ftp.retrlines('LIST')` with the command `ftp.nlst()` -> what retrlines does is simply outputs the current command, and nlst stores the return into your variable (majorly simplified)